# How do I report things I find wrong with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: grub2, 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 is different with Gnome 3 but that is okay :)

I made 3 partitions on my 240Gb SSD, 110Gb for my beloved Ubuntu 16.04 and another 110Gb for my new Ubuntu 18.04 and a 20Gb SWAP (that I should have made smaller) but it is all working quite fine and dandy. Grub however is a ghastly horrible mess and is not happy at all. It is black and messy with a super large font (small resolution) and when I select the options GRUB has it becomes a white and black warped scribble mess. It works, quiet fine but it looks like my cat smacked it a few times with her paw and it is still feeling sorry for itself. So where do I report this stuff and how do I fix grub so I can see properly what my boot options are??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: In addition to report bugs, you can discuss features and bugs at the following [Ubuntu Forum for the developing release](https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427)